# Why is same command for selecting files locally not working in CircleCI?

Tags: ruby, circleci

Locally I can do

```
$ TESTFILES=$(find . -name "*_spec*.rb")
$ rspec -- ${TESTFILES}
```

and 2 tests run.

But when I have that code in CircleCI I get

```
uninitialized constant Diff
```

I am using Ruby 2.4.0.

Comment: I can think of various reasons, like a different load order or a gem that you installed manually on your machine but that doesn't exist on the CI server. Do you know were `Diff` is coming from? Is it one of your classes or is it from a gem you are using?

Comment: `rspec -- **/*_spec*.rb` should be equivalent to your snippet.

Comment: This is a test project, mostly empty.  I don't have Diff as a class or gem.  It feels like something is broken with the ruby version or the rspec gem or something @spickermann

Comment: Are you using the Machine or the Docker executor? What parent image are you using?